# Perfomance testing using IE11 And Google Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record in Script in Jmeter while using IE as browser but nothing is getting recorded.
Can just wanted a bit guidence on how to record script using IE11 or Chrome as browser .

Comment: there are plenty of tutorials explaining how to record with IE/Chrome/Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Prepare JMeter for recording.

   - The fastest and the easiest way is using JMeter Templates feature. From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image: JMeter Recording Template]
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Prepare browser for recording. Open system proxy configuration dialog (IE and Chrome share the same settings) and make sure your configuration looks like:

   [image: IE Proxy Settings for JMeter]

   - Make sure host is `localhost` (if you are running browser and JMeter on the same machine)
   - Make sure port is `8888`
   - Make sure that there is no `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in "Do not use proxy server for address ..."
3. Install JMeter's self-signed certificate into browser. Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and use the certificate installation dialog to get it installed

   - Click the certificate
   - Click "Install certificate" button

   [image: JMeter certificate installation]
4. Now you should have JMeter and browser prepared for recording.

References:

- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](http://Apache%20JMeter%20proxy%20Step-by-step%20%20%201%20%20/%208)
- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation

---

P.S. You may find easier recording a JMeter test using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates, you will be able just to record JMeter test scenarios from Chrome browser without any infrastructure.